# How to plot grouped data in pandas?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm investigating Titanic dataset. I have grouped data by 'Pclass', 'Survived', 'Sex'.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
titanic_df = pd.read_csv('titanic-data.csv')
titanic_cleaned = titanic_df.drop(['PassengerId', 'Name', 'Ticket', 'Fare', 'Cabin', 'Embarked'], axis=1)
titanic_cleaned.head()

titanic_cleaned.groupby(['Pclass', 'Survived', 'Sex']).size()
```

[image]

How do I plot 'Survived' data for each Plcass per Sex using Matplotlib and Seaborn ?

Comment: please provide text of data and not an image.  I can't copy and paste an image.

Comment: Updated the description. Dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data

Comment: The answer to this question is already [within the seaborn example gallery](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/factorplot_bars.html)